# PyQt and Image in string

Tags: python, pyqt4

Why this code show me a window without image? I try to use QByteArray instead of StringIO, but i have same result. Anyone know answer?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from StringIO import StringIO
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        cs=StringIO()
        cs.write(open("image.jpeg",'rb').read())
        p = QtGui.QPixmap()
        p.loadFromData(cs.getvalue())
        lbl=QtGui.QLabel()
        lbl.setPixmap(p)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(lbl)
        self.move(20, 30)
        self.setWindowTitle('Picture')
        self.show()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

UPDATE:
I need show image from StringIO (or any another object in RAM), because i downloading it with pycurl without saving to HDD.

UPDATE 2:
Added Layout using, like Petr Viktorin advised, but code still not working.

UPDATE 3:
@Petr Viktorin, this code work only when i want to display PNG file, but when image - Jpeg/jpg, i see empty form. Maybe problem in QPixmap?

UPDATE 4:
Tested with various images, but...
http://i39.tinypic.com/3535mqd.jpg Where problem?

Comment: Isn't this a much easier solution? `pic = QtGui.QPixmap(":/img/image.png")`

Comment: The code works for me using a PNG, JPG, or SVG file. Maybe there's something wrong with the image file you're using. Try some different jpg files and load them with `p.loadFromData(cs.getvalue(), 'JPG')
`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't add the label to the mainwindow. The easiest solution is:

```
lbl=QtGui.QLabel(self)
```

And the proper solution is using some [layout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/layout.html), so the window will have the appropriate size. Add this after `lbl.setPixmap(p)`:

```
layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
layout.addWidget(lbl)
```